# Closing all opened tabs except the first tab/main tab using webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, tabs, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone tell me how to close all opened tabs except the first tab/main tab using webdriver?

I tried below, but it is closing all tabs including first tab as well.

```
public static void closeTabs() {
    String wh1=driver.getWindowHandle();
    String cwh=null;
    while(wh1!=cwh)
    {   
    new Actions(driver).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.NUMPAD1).perform();
    driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.TAB);
    cwh=driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"w");
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Can someone help me, how to close the tabs ..?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Get all the window handles then iterate through them, switching webdriver to the new handle, then calling the close method. Obviously skip this for the original handle, then switch back to the remaining handle.

Something like;

```
    String originalHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

    //Do something to open new tabs

    for(String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        if (!handle.equals(originalHandle)) {
            driver.switchTo().window(handle);
            driver.close();
        }
    }

    driver.switchTo().window(originalHandle);
```

Comment: I'm wondering why `driver.switchTo().window(handle).close()` not work, but `driver.switchTo().window(handle);
            driver.close();` work

Comment: `driver.switchTo().window(handle)` switches the current window context but does return a wendriver object

Answer (score 2):

I did the following to close all windows but the main one:

```
// Find out which handle is the one of the main window
String mainWindow = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

// Get a list of all windows, except the main window
driver.WindowHandles.Where(w => w != mainWindow).ToList()
    // For each window found
    .ForEach(w =>
    {
        // switch to the window
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(w);

        // close the window
        driver.Close();
    });

// At the end, come back to the main window
driver.SwitchTo().Window(mainWindow);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it should work:

```
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
  {
    if (winHandle == driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[driver.getWindowHandles().size()-1])     
     {
      continue;
     }
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    driver.close();
  }
```

Comment: Hi Abhi, Its closing entire window, not the Tabs. But I want to close all tabs except first Tab in a single/same window. Pls tell me how to do this? Pls let me know if you need any other info regarding this..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(int i = driver.getWindowHandles().size() -1 ; i > 0 ; i--){

        String winHandle = driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[i].toString();

        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);

        driver.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an utility method to switch to the required window as shown below

```
public class Utility 
{
    public static WebDriver getHandleToWindow(String title){

        //parentWindowHandle = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getWindowHandle(); // save the current window handle.
        WebDriver popup = null;
        Set<String> windowIterator = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().getWindowHandles();
        System.err.println("No of windows :  " + windowIterator.size());
        for (String s : windowIterator) {
          String windowHandle = s; 
          popup = WebDriverInitialize.getDriver().switchTo().window(windowHandle);
          System.out.println("Window Title : " + popup.getTitle());
          System.out.println("Window Url : " + popup.getCurrentUrl());
          if (popup.getTitle().equals(title) ){
              System.out.println("Selected Window Title : " + popup.getTitle());
              return popup;
          }

        }
                System.out.println("Window Title :" + popup.getTitle());
                System.out.println();
            return popup;
        }
}
```

It will take you to desired window once title of the window is passed as parameter. In your case you can do.

```
Webdriver childDriver = Utility.getHandleToWindow("titleOfChildWindow");
childDriver.close();
```

and then again switch to parent window using the same method

```
Webdriver parentDriver = Utility.getHandleToWindow("titleOfParentWindow");
```

This method works effectively when dealing with multiple windows.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone was looking for a VBA SeleniumBasic ChromeDriver solution, Here you go.

```
Dim TabA as String
TabA = MyChromeDriver.Windows.Item(1).Title
Do While MyChromeDriver.Windows.Count > 1
     MyChromeDriver.Windows.Item(MyChromeDriver.Windows.Count).Close
Loop
On Error Resume Next
     MyChromeDriver.SwitchToWindowByTitle TabA
On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you clear picture,
Will be in this sequential order:

- Create a new tab
- Switch to it
- Do something in the new tab
- Close the new tab
- Switch back to our original tab

```
// save a reference to our original tab's window handle
var originalTabInstance = myWebDriverInstance.CurrentWindowHandle;

// execute some JavaScript to open a new window
myWebDriverInstance.ExecuteJavaScript("window.open();");

// save a reference to our new tab's window handle, this would be the last entry in the WindowHandles collection
var newTabInstance = myWebDriverInstance.WindowHandles[Driver.Instance.WindowHandles.Count - 1];

// switch our WebDriver to the new tab's window handle
myWebDriverInstance.SwitchTo().Window(newTabInstance);

// lets navigate to a web site in our new tab
myWebDriverInstance.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.crowbarsolutions.com");

// now lets close our new tab
myWebDriverInstance.ExecuteJavaScript("window.close();");

// and switch our WebDriver back to the original tab's window handle
myWebDriverInstance.SwitchTo().Window(originalTabInstance);

// and have our WebDriver focus on the main document in the page to send commands to myWebDriverInstance.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```