# How to open new session of chromedriver after driver.quit?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I'm trying to run two feature files (Cucumber + JUnit) and I need to close browser between features. But after closing, second feature couldn't init new session and I'm getting

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Session ID is
>   null.

Using WebDriver after calling `quit()`. How can I avoid this error?

I have below code for the same :

```
 @Before
public void initPage(){
    loginPage = PageObjectFactory.getPageObject(LoginPage.class);
    loginPage.loadPage();
}

@Given("^user login to stg \"([^\"]*)\" with \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void userLoginToStgWithAnd(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2) throws Throwable {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;
    input = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/application.properties");
    prop.load(input);

    arg0 = System.getProperty("url");
    arg1 = prop.getProperty("user.username");
    arg2 = System.getProperty("user.password");
    Map<IElement, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put(loginPage.stgPassword, arg2);
    map.put(loginPage.stgUsername, arg1);
    driver = WebDriverConfig.setChromeProfile();
    driver.get(arg0);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    loginPage.waitForJStoLoad();
    loginPage.fillForm(map);
    loginPage.clickStgLogin();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}

@And("^user logout$")
public void userLogout() throws Throwable {
    loginPage.waitForJStoLoad();
    loginPage.waitForAngular();
    loginPage.openUserProfile();
    loginPage.clickLogout();
    loginPage.waitForJStoLoad();
    driver.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
driver.quit();
driver = null; 
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I've got org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?

Comment: make sure you are initializing with the correct browser driver. I just wrote chrome driver as a reference!

Comment: Yes, I'm using chromedriver. And this solution doesn't work

Comment: There might be a possibility that you are making a logical error! Make sure driver is not nullified i.e. driver = null; before calling driver.quit()
Also if you using a static variable of WebDriver, try using non static variable

Comment: Also, Kill chromedriver instances from the task manager. and use driver.close(); just before the driver.quit(); statement I see you are using that in a function or during test execution, use it just before driver.quit();

Comment: I'm curious - what does `driver = null` do? If the variable `driver` is immediately changed to the result of `new ChromeDriver()`, I'm not sure how nullifying it can have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to close browser then you can use

```
 driver.close() //in java, this will close only active browser, session will not killed.
```

This link will helps you for more info [How to close the whole browser window by keeping the webDriver active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286094/how-to-close-the-whole-browser-window-by-keeping-the-webdriver-active)

Comment: If I'm using driver.close(), I get folowwing error:
org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: hey use driver.close instead of driver.quit. if you use driver.quit then session will be ended so we cant use it. need to start driver again.

Comment: But I've just said, that when I'm using driver.close, I'm gettig no such session error

Comment: code looks good. there is no driver.quit so we cant get that exception generally. may be this     loginPage.clickLogout(); method may contains driver.quit. could you plz look once if not

Comment: generally, we known SessionNotFoundException occurs when we use driver after driver.quit. so need to check script, are we using driver instance even after quit?

Comment: In loginPage.clickLogout(); metho I only clicking on button.

As for next comment - after driver.close I want to open browser and run another Feature file

Comment: maybe you know the way, how I can clear cache of Chrome browser (not cookies)?