# Error in fire fox selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Recently, bump into this issues with selenium firefox driver. 
Thanks in advance

**Set UP**

os.name: 'Mac OS X',

os.arch: 'x86_64',

os.version: '10.12.6',

java.version: '1.8.0_131'

**Firefox version** 56.0.1 (64-bit)

***Gecko Driver***  Latest 0.19.0

> The error shows failed:
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Tried to run command
>   without establishing a connection

I tried different ways to tackle it but always come with the same error. 
1. update all the selenium test driver to the latest
2. specify the directory export PATH = $PATH driverDir

***My code***

```
  package automationFramework;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class GeckoDriver {
    private static WebDriver driver;
    public static int random = 0;
    private String baseURL;
    // @BeforeClass : Executes only once for the Test-Class.
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setting_SystemProperties(){
        System.out.println("System Properties seting Key value.");

    }
    // @Before      : To execute once before ever Test.
    @Before
    public void test_Setup(){
        System.out.println("Launching Browser");
        if (random == 0) {
            System.out.println("Start Chrome Browser Testing ");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/Fannity/Desktop/Drivers/geckodriver");  // Chrome Driver Location.
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        System.out.println("Session ID : " + ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId() );
    }

    @Test
    public void selenium_ScreenShot() throws IOException {
        baseURL = "https://www.google.com/";
        driver.get(baseURL);
        System.out.println("Selenium Screen shot.");
        File screenshotFile = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshotFile, new File("/Users/Fannity/Desktop/JUNIT-Selenium.jpg"));
        random += 1;
    }

    // @After       : To execute once after ever Test.
    @After
    public void test_Cleaning(){
        System.out.println("Closing Browser");
        baseURL = null;
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
    // @AfterClass  : Executes only once before Terminating the Test-Class.
    @AfterClass
    public static void clearing_SystemProperties(){
        System.out.println("System Property Removing Key value.");
        System.clearProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver");
    }
}
```

***ERROR***

https://gist.github.com/Fenici/f82f885486de37ae110fda8d7430df6e

Comment: What version of Firefox do you have? Make sure it's at least v 55

Comment: its latest firefox , i haven't try the firefox nighty on mac , @Hac , how to call firefox nighty in mac ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
@After
    public void test_Cleaning(){
        System.out.println("Closing Browser");
        baseURL = null;
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Try only with `close()`.
Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35286345/3881320).

Comment: Based on your linked discussion, I found it more wise to select to use only `driver.quit()` as "If you do not use driver.quit at the end of program, WebDriver session will not close properly and files would not be cleared off memory." Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We generally get this , if we use `driver.close()` and `driver.quit()` together  so it would be better if you remove `driver.close()`;

```
 public void test_Cleaning(){
        System.out.println("Closing Browser");
        baseURL = null;
        driver.quit();
    }
```