# Scenario outline doesnt' work when running second example

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

I have a problem with execute scenario outline with more than 1 example.
I've tried to clear session but it didint work

Here is the code

```
namespace AutomationPractice
{
  [Binding]
  public class LoginSteps
  {
    [BeforeScenario("LoginProperly")]
    public static void BeforeScenario()
    {
        Browser.Initialize();
    }

    [AfterScenario("LoginProperly")]
    public static void AfterScenario()
    {
        Browser.ClearSession();
        Browser.Close();

    }


    [Given(@"I am on login page")]
    public void GivenIAmOnLoginPage()
    {

        Pages.Navigation.GoToSignIn();
    }

    [Given(@"I have completed the form with '(.*)' and '(.*)'")]
    public void GivenIHaveCompletedTheFormWithAnd(string email, string password)
    {
        Pages.Login.LogIn(email, password);
    }

    [When(@"I press Submit")]
    public void WhenIPressSubmit()
    {
        Pages.Login.ClickLogin();
    }

    [Then(@"I should see my account panel")]
    public void ThenIShouldSeeMyAccountPanel()
    {

        Pages.Account.IsAt();
```

Here is feature file

```
Feature: Login
   In order to use my account
   As an application user
   I want to be able to log in and log out

@LoginProperly
Scenario Outline: Login with correct Email adress and Password
Given I am on login page
And I have completed the form with '<email>' and '<password>'
When I press Submit
Then I should see my account panel

Examples: 

| email            | password |
| tescik@gmail.com | 11111    |
| test             | test     |
```

After first scenario, when running second scenario one by one (email = test, password= test)  there is error message

[image]

What can i do to fix it?

Comment: I think that `Browser.Close` will close that last window and with that ends the browser process as well as the WebDriver session. You might want to clearcookies and stuff like that but **not** call close if you need the webdriver to stay active. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35286345/578411

Comment: So how the test should look like? I just want to end first scenario and start new one regardless of the first one

Comment: Browser.DeleteAllCookies without Browser.Close fixed problem.
Thanks