# Edge Selenium shows the error: "Message: The specified window could not be found."

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, microsoft-edge

I use selenium with edge.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get("xxxxx")
```

When I opened an edge window,it will show 
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: The specified window could not be found.` when I run this code.

In other words, if I run this code when there is no edge window,it run well without exception.

How could I run selenium with edge when I has opened a edge window?

About *Edge* version:

```
Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from selenium import webdriver
>
> driver = webdriver.Edge()
>
> driver.get("xxxxx")

I have tested above code, but can't reproduce the problem. As far as I know, when we using selenium Edge webdriver with the legacy version Edge (Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0), it will auto close the existing Edge instance.

Please check your code, whether you want to switch handle to another window? Generally, this exception will throw when window target to be switched doesn’t exist, you could check [this article](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html).

Besides, from your description, the code runs well without exception if there is no Edge window. I suppose perhaps there have some process which is doing the automation test with the existing Edge browser window. Or, the existing Edge browser window is opened by the selenium Edge web driver, and it didn't close, so, it will show this exception.

To solve this issue, we need to close the Edge browser window or Edge browser process(from the Task Manager).

Besides, I suggest you could try to refer the following code, use try statement to catch the exception and remember to add [close() and quit() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286094/how-to-close-the-whole-browser-window-by-keeping-the-webdriver-active) to close the close the browser session at the end of automation test.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver 

print("*******************")

try:
    driver = webdriver.Edge();

    driver.get("https://www.bing.com")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
except NoSuchWindowException:
    print("Window disappeared, seems like it was closed manually") 

print("*******************")
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we closed open Edge browsers and re-ran the test. This worked!