# How to switch to newly opened tab and close it?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have used the below two methods to switch to the tab and close it.But unfortunately, none of them are useful.Please provide alternate methods.

sol1:

```
public static void switchTab()
            {
                try{
                    webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
                    webDriver.close();
                    webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){

                        e.printStackTrace();}
                    }
                }
```

Here, driver is closing the whole browser instead of closing the tab.

sol2:

```
public void switchTab(){
try{
ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (webDriver.getWindowHandles());

webDriver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
webDriver.close();
webDriver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(0));
}
catch(Exception e){

    e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

This is throwing index out of bounds exception as there is no other window opened.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
   String homeWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
       Set<String> allWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();

        //Use Iterator to iterate over windows
        Iterator<String> windowIterator =  allWindows.iterator();

        //Verify next window is available
        while(windowIterator.hasNext()){

            //Store the Recruiter window id
            String childWindow = windowIterator.next();

            //Here we will compare if parent window is not equal to child window 
            if (homeWindow.equals(childWindow)){
                driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);

            //switch here to your desired window/tab and perform your action
                driver.close();
            }
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for the code. But this is also closing the whole browser window instead of just closing the tab. :(

Comment: ohh! try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493572/closing-all-opened-tabs-except-the-first-tab-main-tab-using-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

If Understand correctly then, this will might help
put this in function block.

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://google.com");
    String gettitle = driver.getTitle();

    String windowHandel = driver.getWindowHandle();

    System.out.println(windowHandel + " " + gettitle);

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"t");
    ArrayList tabs = new ArrayList(driver.getWindowHandles());

    System.out.println(tabs.size());
    driver.switchTo().window((String) tabs.get(0));

    gettitle ="";

    driver.get("http://bing.com");

    gettitle = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(tabs.get(0).toString() + " " + gettitle);


    driver.switchTo().window(windowHandel);     

    Thread.sleep(3000);

    Actions actionObj = new Actions(driver);
    actionObj.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
             .sendKeys(Keys.chord("w"))
             .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
             .perform();

    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```