# How to get all open tabs in browsers using Java

Tags: java, google-chrome, batch-file, mozilla

In Java I want to fetch all open tabs from Google Chrome/Mozilla Firefox. I used Jacob API to do this for Internet Explorer. Now I'm looking for something that can be used for most of the browsers.
I dont want to use selenium as it requires all kind of drivers at user's end. I want to keep setup requirements at minimum. if there's an alternative to it, please let me know.
I am preferring using some batch file. I found some commands which can tell me what browsers are installed in a system and I also found some code which checks if open tabs have some specific keyword in title. But I don't understand it completely so can't tweak it enough to get my desired result.
Below is the code:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%i in (
   mshta "javascript:Code(close(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write(clipboardData.getData('Text'))));"
) do (
 echo "%%i"| find "stackoverflow" >nul 2>&1 && (
    echo stackoverflow is open
 )
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you check [Closing all opened tabs except the first tab/main tab using webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493572/closing-all-opened-tabs-except-the-first-tab-main-tab-using-webdriver) and just get first part of the accepted answer will solve your question

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to see from java what all tabs are open in google chrome/ mozilla"?Do you want to fetch unique reference from each tab?

Comment: i actually want to list all tabs that are open using a java code. title and URL i need from each tab

Comment: @JordiCastilla: the answer you have suggested uses selenium. I am preferring using something else as using selenium will increase setup requirements at client side. Some of my users don't use selenium.

Comment: @raginivyas Have you got an answer ?

Comment: @AbdulrahmanFalyoun without selenium? no..